# Can someone give a general rule for working with SQL Rollup NULL values?

Tags: mysql

So we were trying to replace the NULL values created by "WITH ROLLUP" with something meaningful (in this example replaced by the meaningfull value 1) and observed an strange behavior (probably try that with your *Sql-DB as well).

*Query*:

```
SELECT
    IF(a <=> NULL, 1, a) as v1,
    IF( a IS NULL, 1, a ) as v2,
    IF( a IS NOT NULL, a, 1 ) as v3,
    IF( ISNULL(a), 1, a ) as v4,
    IF( !ISNULL(a), a, 1 ) as v5,
    IF( !!ISNULL(a), 1, a ) as v6,
    IFNULL( a, 1 ) as v7
FROM
    (SELECT 1 as a) as tmp
GROUP BY
    a WITH ROLLUP
```

*Result*:

```
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| v1   | v2   | v3   | v4   | v5   | v6   | v7   |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
|    1 | NULL |    1 | NULL |    1 | NULL |    1 |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

So what is the general rule here???

*Explaination*:

What we are doing here is using different methods to replace the NULL value in the last row with something meaningful, but some methods fail, some methods work, are these methods stable throughout different MySQL versions? What's about other sql dialects? I'm confused about this arbitrary behaviour of our mysql db v5.5.28